# Can flying monsters fly diagonally upwards?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Can flying monsters fly fiagonally upwards?

I've got this in part of my fortress. Could a monster in level -2 get to level -1 somehow?

```
          #####
Level -1: #++X#
          #####

Level -2: #####
          #..##
          #####

# natural stone
+ constructed floor
X up/down staircase
. empty space
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A flying entity can travel one z level up or down at the same time that they travel 1 tile on the x or y direction.

if you want to secure your fortress, you should change your up/down staircase to just an up stairs, or dig out an up stair below your up/down stair and then construct flooring over both the open spaces.